# Self host gitlab using caddy

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, caddy

I'm trying to install and host gitlab, but it requires and pulls in Nginx. Which would be fine, except I use Caddy and Caddy doesn't play well with Nginx and has to be disabled for Nginx to even start.

I like Caddy a lot, especially the built in file server, so just switching completely to Nginx isn't an option. I also have no interest in trying to do firewall redirects to try to use Nginx on a nonstandard port.

Is there any way to use gitlab without nginx, eg Caddy? There's no official documentation and the last thing I tried from an online forum completely broke my gitlab install and only pertained to Apache which I'm not using

My system is a dedicated cloud server running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Put it in its own virtual machine. It's 2020, we don't have monolithic multipurpose servers anymore.

Comment: @MichaelHampton you mean use docker? it's 2020 afterall

Comment: @JacobEvans I suppose if you really wanted to and GitLab supported it, you could.

Comment: @MichaelHampton They have do official images. https://hub.docker.com/r/gitlab/gitlab-ce

Comment: To be fair I did try the docker images but ran into the same problem that Caddy doesn't play well with other services binding to the same port

Comment: Hello from the future, and I no longer use caddy nor gitlab for the exact same reasons this question was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from unixandria is correct for when it's from. Things have changed a little since then.

There's now this official section on [GitLab Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server).

Also, GitLab 13.5 changed the location of the unix socket, so the Caddyfile should have this now:

```
git.example.com {
    reverse_proxy unix//var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out.

GitLab doesn't listen on a port but a Unix socket. Luckily we can configure Caddy to reverse proxy to the socket in the Caddyfile like so:

```
git.example.com {
     reverse_proxy * unix//var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket
}
```

Make sure `caddy` user is in `git` and `gitlab-www` groups and vice versa.

In /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb make sure these are configured as such:

```
nginx['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['caddy']
web_server['username'] = 'gitlab-www'
web_server['group'] = 'gitlab-www' 
web_server['uid'] = nil
web_server['gid'] = nil
web_server['shell'] = '/bin/false' 
web_server['home'] = '/var/opt/gitlab/nginx'
```

Then do

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo systemctl restart caddy (or restart Caddy manually if you don't use systemd)
```

I've only tested with the official caddy and GitLab-EE packages on Ubuntu 20.04, and don't configure Caddy via API, but this should work for standard installs of GitLab.